# How do I get the @google.com id of a Google Calendar event?

Tags: google-calendar

If you follow the tutorial [Quickstart: Managing Responses for Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms), you'll notice that it references calendar events using an event id ([`event.getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getId())).

This an email address of the form gkp8em6kg4uebp44ia3qh6e7he5@google.com

If I already have a pre-existing calendar event, how do I get its id?

Preferably looking for a solution that doesn't involve Google Apps Scripts and can be done via UI alone.

It needs to be in this exact format because I plan on (eventually) creating a Google Apps Script to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

This was [asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755413/how-can-i-find-the-event-id-of-my-google-calendar-event).

Easiest solution is to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51704714/35690):

> 1. Go to the event debugging URL at https://www.google.com/calendar/render?gsessionid=OK&eventdeb=1
> 2. Double click to view the affected event.
> 3. Select the drop down menu 'More Actions'.
> 4. Click on the 'Troubleshooting Info'.
> 5. Copy the text that appears and paste it in your reply to support.

Then append `@google.com` to it.